Lambda function url with AWS cloudfront error 403 with cache policy in-place
I use Cloud Front with Lambda Function URL as one of the origin.

I get 403 error when I use POST request to fetch some data using the Authorization header(Bearer token).

I tried by added Cache Policy to allow Authorization header but the request it is not hitting the Lambda instead I get 403 Forbidden.

If I try without the Authorization header, it can reach the Lambda.
Any ideas?
Thanks



It happens because AWS uses Authorization header for its Signature V4.
Normally it would replace the header value coming from the client with the signature, but if you force it to retain that value the Lambda cannot authenticate the request and returns 403.
Possible solutions:

use a different header, e.g. x-my-app-auth: Bearer some-JWT
make the function public with Auth: NONE and disable request signing in CloudFront access policy

This blog post goes into more detail: https://dev.to/rimutaka/aws-lambda-with-cloudfront-configuration-guide-27lj
